# a question about using method of characteristics to solve Hunter-Saxton equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am reading the original paper (Ref.1) by Hunter and Saxton on solving the now famous PDE  for $u(x,t)$ using method of characteristics:
$$ \left(u_{t}+uu_{x}\right)_x=\tfrac12(u_x)^2,\qquad u(x,0)=F(x)\tag{1}$$

Their steps go like this:
Suppose that $u(x, t)$ is a smooth solution of Eq.(1). We introduce a characteristic coordinate $\xi$, where
$$x=X(\xi,t),\qquad U(\xi, t)=u[X(\xi,t),t],\tag{2}$$
and $X(\xi, t)$ satisfies
$$X_t=U,\qquad X(\xi,0)=\xi\tag{3}$$

We also define
$$V(\xi, t) =X_\xi(\xi, t)\tag{4}$$

It then follows from Eq.(1) that $V$ satisfies
$$VV_{tt}=\tfrac12 (V_t)^2,\quad V(\xi, 0)=1,\quad V_t(\xi,0)=F'(\xi)\tag{5}.$$.

***Questions***
(1) Where are the steps that I am missing in getting Eq.(5)?

Define $\omega=u_x$, then $\omega(x,t)$ satisfies
$$ \omega_{t}+u\omega_{x}+\tfrac12\omega^2=0\tag{6}$$

***Questions***
(2) Are they obtaining Eq.(6) from Eq.(5) by using method of characteristics?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Ref.1:  J. K. HUNTER AND R. SAXTON, DYNAMICS OF DIRECTOR FIELDS,
SIAM J. APPL. MATH. Vol. 51, No. 6, pp. 1498-1521, December 1991

Comment: To get to (5), I believe it's just a change of variables from $x,t$ to $\xi,t$. $\partial_x = ( \partial_x \xi ) \partial_\xi$ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference paper by Alejandro Sarria (arXiv:1307.4504) titled "Global estimates and blow-up criteria for the generalized Hunter-Saxton system".   The 2-component generalization Hunter-Saxton equation was solved using method of characteristics.

I will just copy a few steps here in order to close this open problem.

First we rewrite (1) as:
$$u_{xt}+u u_{xx}=(-\tfrac12)(u_{x})^2\tag{1B}.$$

From (2) and (3) above (in the question area), we obtain
$$X_{t\xi}=U_\xi=u_x\,X_\xi\tag{2B}.$$
Replacing $X_\xi$ with $V$ (cf.(4) ) leads to
$$V^{-1}V_{t}=u_x\,\tag{3B}.$$

On the other hand, the left hand side of (1B) is just:
$$\frac{\mathrm{D}}{\mathrm{D}t}u_x[X(\xi,t),t]=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+X_t\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\right)u_x.\qquad \because X_t=U\tag{4B}$$

Thus we can rewrite (1B) as:

$$\left(V^{-1}V_{t}\right)_t=-\tfrac12\left(V^{-1}V_{t}\right)^2.\,\tag{5B}$$

or

$$\frac{VV_{tt}}{V^2}=\frac{(1-\tfrac12)(V_{t})^2}{V^2}.\,\tag{6B}$$

Eq.(6B) is just Eq.(5).